# Raster image as PDF

Tags: pdf

I'm trying to use PDF as a container to push a raster image through CUPS. The submitted example works, but the image becomes scaled. I use firefox as a test to view the PDF and set zoom to 100%.

Are there any "plain" alternative to the cm command in object #6 to just set the position, if necceccary? I don't want to twist the image in any ways. 1 pixel in should be 1 pixel out. Tried to leave out the cm, but got a blank page.

Can the structure be simplified? Tried to point /contents in object #3 directly to the XObject and leave out objects #6 and #4. Then only a blank page is displayed.

Any help. please?

```
%PDF-1.7
%xxxxxx

1 0 obj
    << /Type /Catalog
        /Pages 2 0 R
    >>
endobj

2 0 obj
    << /Type /Pages
        /Kids [3 0 R]
        /Count 1
        /MediaBox [5 5 1240 1705]
  >>
endobj

3 0 obj
    <<  /Type /Page
        /Parent 1 0 R
        /Resources 4 0 R
        /Contents 6 0 R
    >>
endobj

4 0 obj
    <<  /ProcSet [ /PDF /ImageB ]
        /XObject << /Im1 5 0 R >>
    >>
endobj

5 0 obj
    <<  /Type /XObject
        /Subtype /Image
        /Width 16
        /Height 16
        /ColorSpace /DeviceGray
        /BitsPerComponent 8
        /Length 769
        /Filter /ASCIIHexDecode
    >>
stream
00 00 ff ff 7f 7f ff ff 00 00 ff ff 7f 7f ff ff
14 lines deleted
00 00 ff ff 7f 7f ff ff 00 00 ff ff 7f 7f ff ff >
endstream
endobj

6 0 obj
    << /Length 40 >>
stream
    16 0 0 16 0 0 cm
    /Im1 Do
endstream
endobj

xref
0 7
0000000000 65535 f 
0000000018 00000 n 
0000000077 00000 n 
0000000180 00000 n
0000000284 00000 n
0000000369 00000 n
0000001357 00000 n
trailer
    <<  /Root 1 0 R
        /Size 7
    >>
startxref
1442
%%EOF
```

Comment: Instead of `16 0 0 16 0 0` use `w 0 0 h x y` where `w` and `h` are the width and height of your image and `x` and `y` are the position on the page. And don't forget to use the correct width and height values in object 5, too.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting (nice) use of text/pdf

[image]

@mkl has given sound advice in his comment, we can see the media is way bigger than the 8 pairs of bars. So currently they occupy 16 pts by 16 points at ground zer0 (Lower Left)

You have several options, the two most obvious are

- you can reduce the media
- or up scale the image.

[image]

Or alter both.

from comments you say pixel to pixel but PDF does not count in pure pixel dpi as we may consider. Let's see you want media to match image that's easy drop media to 16  x 16, however your media location is off which causes default to letter shape media. Lets suggest first step is add the image as greyscale byte stream and **put media** and crop boxes **into the page definition**. (Note because of notepad raw text editing I have not checked the `xref` table so am sure that should be wrong. **P.S as requested 4 is in 3 so 5 becomes 4 etc.**

```
%PDF-1.7
%µ¶

1 0 obj
<</Type/Catalog/Pages 2 0 R>>
endobj

2 0 obj
<</Type/Pages/Kids[3 0 R]/Count 1>>
endobj

3 0 obj
<</Type/Page/MediaBox[0 0 16 16]/CropBox[0 0 16 16]/Parent 2 0 R/Resources<</XObject<</Im1 4 0 R>>>>/Contents 5 0 R>>
endobj

4 0 obj
<</Type/XObject/Subtype/Image/Width 16/Height 16/ColorSpace/DeviceGray/BitsPerComponent 8/Length 521/Filter/ASCIIHexDecode>>
stream
0000ffff7f7fffff0000ffff7f7fffff0000ffff7f7fffff0000ffff7f7fffff
0000ffff7f7fffff0000ffff7f7fffff0000ffff7f7fffff0000ffff7f7fffff
0000ffff7f7fffff0000ffff7f7fffff0000ffff7f7fffff0000ffff7f7fffff
0000ffff7f7fffff0000ffff7f7fffff0000ffff7f7fffff0000ffff7f7fffff
0000ffff7f7fffff0000ffff7f7fffff0000ffff7f7fffff0000ffff7f7fffff
0000ffff7f7fffff0000ffff7f7fffff0000ffff7f7fffff0000ffff7f7fffff
0000ffff7f7fffff0000ffff7f7fffff0000ffff7f7fffff0000ffff7f7fffff
0000ffff7f7fffff0000ffff7f7fffff0000ffff7f7fffff0000ffff7f7fffff
>
endstream
endobj

5 0 obj
<</Length 33>>
stream
q
16 0 0 16 0 0 cm
/Im1 Do
Q
q
Q

endstream
endobj

xref
0 6
0000000000 65536 f 
0000000016 00000 n 
0000000062 00000 n 
0000000153 00000 n 
0000000248 00000 n 
0000000928 00000 n 

trailer
<</Size 6/Root 1 0 R>>
startxref
1010
%%EOF
```

At this point you can decide how to upscale the page and or image as relative objects, as per @mkl 's advice.

As it stands image is 0.564444... cm (0.2222...") so decide on target ratio and upscale to desire.

[image]

Lets guess your sample was 5 units up and to the right so let's pad media by 10 units to 42 and double the pixel ratio without adding pixels just their size.

we need to increase media and crop to 42 (however you can drop crop to `5 5 32 32` if you wish)

```
3 0 obj
<</Type/Page/MediaBox[0 0 42 42]/CropBox[0 0 42 42]/Parent 2 0 R/Resources<</XObject<</Im1 4 0 R>>>>/Contents 5 0 R>>
endobj
```

and double the image to scale as 32 units at offset `5 5`

```
5 0 obj
<</Length 29>>
stream
q
32 0 0 32 5 5 cm
/Im1 Do
Q

endstream
endobj
```

A point to note the number of bytes has generally not changed (there are no added pixels) it is just the area of image has changed so theoretic dpi is halved but there is no real dpi definition.

[image]

Comment: A follow-up question.